# Creating design in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to replicate a ui in flutter . Image is given below . But I am having hard time to figure out how to get the bottom design of the box . The Content inside is not important . What I want is the box style .

Right now what I am thinking is creating two widget .  One with this
[image]

and remaining in another widget . Is there better alternative to do this
Can anyone help me how to achieve this . Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could achieve the result in the image below in the way you described.

[image: Two rectangles overlapping each other]

I used a [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) to create the two boxes and set the `decoration` to create the top radius border. Placing the two items in a `Column` won't work because they need to overlap each other.

To achieve this behavior you will need to use [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html).

The code is described below:

```
  Widget _buildBox(Color boxColor) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: boxColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(40), topRight: Radius.circular(40))),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            child: _buildBox(Colors.deepPurple),
            width: 400.0,
            height: 300.0,
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: _buildBox(Colors.purpleAccent),
            top: 200.0,
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```